# Hibernate One to One mapping behaving as One to many

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-one

I am using a below `One to one mapping` between `Account and Company`.Company table has `foreign key 'account_id'`.Below is the code

```
@Entity
public class Company{
    ................
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "account_id")
    private Account account;
    ................
}

@Entity
public class Account{
    ................
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="account")
    private Company company;
    ...............
}
```

Now, above mapping means, For an `Account`, only one `company` can be related to it and vice-versa.

Now, Account table row would be inserted from somewhere else and save company would need to update one Account table column. Now, Save company request would contain company details and account id company relates to. On first request, company data is saved to company table with account id, but on subsequent requests for a particular `account id`, new row is getting inserted in company table even though only one company row should be created for a particular `account id`.

I was expecting some exception that only one company can be associated with a particular account. May i know the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When saving a new company having a given account, Hibernate will not check that no other company also has another account. And even if it checked you wouldn't have any guarantee, because several concurrent transactions should do that check in parallel, and then insert in parallel.

The only way to prevent that from occurring is to let the database itself prevent it, and that will happen if you let Hibernate generate the schema: there should be a unique constraint on the `account_id` column of the `company` table. If you generate your schema yourself, just make sure to create such a unique constraint.

Once the constraint exists, a transaction trying to insert a company with an account that is already associated to another company would get an exception from the database and rollback.

Comment: Thanks JB. I added unique = true in my hibernate entity like @JoinColumn(name = "account_id", unique = true)
 private Account account; but still it didn't work. However, I didn't add unique constraint at database level. So, do I need to add unique constraint at database level?

Comment: Yes, you have to do that. That's what my answer explains. the `unique=true` attribute in the annotation is only used when Hibernate generates the database schema. It's not used at runtime. So if you don't generate the schema with Hibernate, it doesn't serve any purpose.

Comment: Thanks..it worked...one more thing when do we need to apply such constraints at hibernate level or do we need it at all considering such constraints have been applied at database level..

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "apply such constraints at hibernate level".

Comment: constraint like size or length that can be applied at hibernate level i.e. in entities whereas same we can specify at database level..did i make myself clear now?